# Can't install GitLab on Ubuntu Mate 16.04

Tags: software-installation, packages

I want to install GitLib on my Raspi 3 running Ubuntu Mate 16.04. For this, I followed the steps described for Ubuntu 16.04: https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#ubuntu1604

Step 1 worked as expected. However, I ran into trouble in step 2:

```
christoph@christoph-pi:/tmp$ curl -sS https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
[sudo] password for christoph: 
Detected operating system as Ubuntu/xenial.
Checking for curl...
Detected curl...
Running apt-get update... done.
Installing apt-transport-https... done.
Installing /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gitlab_gitlab-ce.list...done.
Importing packagecloud gpg key... done.
Running apt-get update... done.

The repository is setup! You can now install packages.
christoph@christoph-pi:/tmp$ sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gitlab-ce
```

Switching out `apt-get` for `apt` doesn't work. I tried executing

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get update
```

and then trying to install `gitlab-ce` but it doesn't work, either.

The [installation instructions for the Raspi 2](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#raspberrypi2) mention the same package.

How do I install GitLab? Is the Raspi 3 not supported or does it not work because I'm using Ubuntu Mate?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check what GitLab actually put in your apt sources. if you take a look in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` you should see a gitlab entry. It should include raspberry pi in it somewhere. It may have mistaken Ubuntu Mate as the x86 version and apt is giving up. The link you posted looks a lot like the instructions for x86 (rather than ARM).

The Pi instructions are [here](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#raspberrypi2)

The install script itself more-or-less just runs: (you can view it here https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/raspberry-pi2/script.deb.sh - my line numbers are as per this file)

Add signing key (line 107):

`curl -L "https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/raspberry-pi2/gpgkey" | sudo apt-key add -`

Add Repos (line 108) from https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/raspberry-pi2/config_file.list?os=ubuntu&dist=xenial&source=script

which puts

```
deb https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/raspberry-pi2/ubuntu/ xenial main
deb-src https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/raspberry-pi2/ubuntu/ xenial main
```

in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gitlab_raspberry-pi2.list`

Then `sudo apt-get update`

Then you should see gitlab-ce available.

My experiance with GitLab on the Pi wasn't too good, GitLab itself is great but i don't think the Pi is really up to it, mostly due to the limited memory.